# Perl, what does $|++ do?

Tags: perl

I'm re-factoring some perl code, and as seems to be the case, Perl has some weird constructs that are a pain to look up.

In this case I encountered the following...

```
$|++;
```

This is on a line by itself just after the "use" statements.

What does this command do?

Comment: Don't use `$|++`, use `$| = 1;`.  The former gives the misleading impression that increment and decrement work on $| in the same way those operators work on any other variable, which they don't in the case of this special variable.  See http://perlmonks.org/?node_id=280025

Comment: If you do need a "stackable" effect that one might want to use `++` to achieve, you might consider `local $| = 1;`

Comment: @DavidO: It's interesting that `perldoc` doesn't mention the "magic" behavior of `$|`. Is there anything in the documentation from which you can infer that `$| = 0; $| --;` will set `$|` to 1?

Comment: $|++ because it's easier IMO to hold down the shift key and enter "$|" then bang on the '+' key a couple of times than to release shift and then find the '=' and then the '0' keys.

Comment: @tjd If by "stackable" you mean you can increment it several times, and the effects won't be removed until decrementing several times, this is a good example of the misunderstanding that results by using the ++ operator with $|.  You can increment it 100 times, and its value will still be 1.  Decrementing it a single time will change it back to 0.  Decrementing it twice will flip-flop it back to 1 again.  If that's useful behavior for you, please be sure to put a #comment next to it so people aren't surprised.

Comment: @KeithThompson No, there is nowhere in the POD that I know of explaining the quirky behavior of applying ++ and -- to $|.  However, it has behaved this way as far back as I recall, which is the late 1990's.

Comment: @DavidO, by "stackable" I meant precisely what `local` does, restoring the previous value at the end of the enclosing scope.  Set it to 1 in 100 scopes & at the end of the hundred scopes you get your 0 back....

Comment: But you can use `local $| = 1`, which says what it means.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [perldoc perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html):

> **`$|`**
>
> If set to nonzero, forces a flush right away and after every write or print on the currently selected output channel. Default is 0 (regardless of whether the channel is really buffered by the system or not; `$|` tells you only whether you've asked Perl explicitly to flush after each write). `STDOUT` will typically be line buffered if output is to the terminal and block buffered otherwise. Setting this variable is useful primarily when you are outputting to a pipe or socket, such as when you are running a Perl program under rsh and want to see the output as it's happening. This has no effect on input buffering. See getc for that. See select on how to select the output channel. See also `IO::Handle`.

Therefore, as it always starts as `0`, this increments it to `1`, forcing a flush after every write/print.

You can replace it with the following to be much clearer.

```
use English '-no_match_vars';
$OUTPUT_AUTOFLUSH = 1;
```

Comment: tut tut. If you `use English`, *always* `use English '-no_match_vars'`, or you will incur a regex performance penalty (see [the `English` docs](https://metacpan.org/pod/English#PERFORMANCE) for an explanation).

Comment: Thanks for adding a cleaner alternative.

Answer (score 3):

Looking up variables is best done with perlvar (perldoc perlvar, or http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html)

From that:

> HANDLE->autoflush( EXPR )
>
> $OUTPUT_AUTOFLUSH
>
> $|
>
> If set to nonzero,
>   forces a flush right away and after every write or print on the
>   currently selected output channel. Default is 0 (regardless of whether
>   the channel is really buffered by the system or not; $| tells you only
>   whether you've asked Perl explicitly to flush after each write).
>   STDOUT will typically be line buffered if output is to the terminal
>   and block buffered otherwise. Setting this variable is useful
>   primarily when you are outputting to a pipe or socket, such as when
>   you are running a Perl program under rsh and want to see the output as
>   it's happening. This has no effect on input buffering. See getc for
>   that. See select on how to select the output channel. See also
>   IO::Handle.

++ is the increment operator, which adds one to the variable.

So $|++ sets autoflush true (default 0 + 1 = 1, which boolean evals as true), which forces writes to stdout to not be buffered.

Answer (score 1):

`$|` is one of Perl's special variables.

According to [`perlvar`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html):

> If set to nonzero, forces a flush right away and after every write or print on the currently selected output channel.

Answer (score 1):

If Google is your only source of information, I can understand how looking up special variables in Perl could cause consternation.  Fortunately there is `perldoc`!  Every machine with perl on it should also have `perldoc`.  Use it without command line parameters to get a list of all the Core documentation that comes with your version of Perl.

- To look up all special variables: `perldoc perlvar`
- To look up a specific special variable:`perldoc -v '$|'` ( on *nix,
  use double quotes on Windows)
- To look up perl's list of functions:  `perldoc perlfunc`
- To look up a specific function: `perldoc -f sprintf`
- To look up the operators (including precedence): `perldoc perlop`

Armed with that information, you'll know what happens when you **post-increment** the **Output Autoflush** variable.

As a special bonus, `perldoc.perl.org` can manage all of these jobs with the exception of the `-v` search...

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, it enables autoflush on the selected output filehandle (which is likely `STDOUT`). What nobody else has said, though, is that while you're generally refactoring and neatening up code, you really ought to replace it with the equivalent but much more obvious

```
STDOUT->autoflush(1);
```